# Deduce the density of the sets $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have a question.

Let $b,n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $b \geq 2 $ and $n \geq 1$.

Let's consider the set:

$Q_n = \Bigg\{ \frac{k}{b^n} ,k\in \mathbb{N} , 0 \leq k < b^n \Bigg\}$

I have proven that $Q_n $ is dense in $[0,1]$.

How do I deduce that the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and the [set $\mathbb{D}$ of decimal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal#Decimal_fractions) is dense  in $\mathbb{R}$?

I know that all numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$ are written as the sum of elements in $Q_n$.

Please help me with this question.

Comment: When you write decimal numbers, do you mean rational numbers of the form $\frac{m}{10^p}$ where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $\Bbb Q_n$ is **not** dense. And what do you mean by "decimal numbers"? Every real number has a decimal representation.

Comment: 1) Since $\Bbb D\subset\Bbb Q,$ you only need to prove that $\Bbb D$ is dense in $\Bbb R,$ 2) There are many (equivalent) definitions of "dense". What is yours? 3) It is not $Q_n$ which is dense in $[0,1),$ but $\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}Q_n$ (for a fixed $b\ge2$, @LeeMosher).

Comment: Your formula for $Q_n$ has a flaw which makes it ambiguous. Is $b$, like $n$, to be regarded as a constant given ahead of time? That seems most likely given the wording of your post, but if so then with $n=1$ and $b=2$ we get $Q_1 = \{0,\frac{1}{2}\}$ which certainly is not dense in $[0,1)$ (typing $[0,1[$ gives me the heebie-jeebies). Or, on the other hand, is $b$, like $k$, a free variable in the definition of $Q_n$? In other words, $$Q_n = \{k/b^n \mid k \in \mathbb N, b \in \mathbb N, b \ge 2, 0 \le k < b^n\}$$

Comment: i think $b$ is considered a free variable

Comment: I don't think so @user912835 (see my previous comment). The OP wants to *deduce* the density of $\Bbb D,$ certainly by taking $b=10.$